# How can I change the number of enumerate items?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

Ok, since this question seems to be pretty easy (well I still don't know the answer and didn't find something on this site), I'll try it without MWE: I'd like to know how to change the number of items in `enumerate` environments. Most appreciated would be solutions without additional packages or such...

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The fifth item
  \item The seventh item
\end{enumerate}
```

This should result in

```
5. The fifth item
7. The seventh item
```

and not in the normal items numbered 1 and 2. It probably has to do something with counters!?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Set the `enumi` counter and do it through a command for easiness (for a more general answer, see below):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \newcommand\setItemnumber[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{enumerate}
     \setItemnumber{5}
     \item The fifth item
     \setItemnumber{7}
     \item The seventh item
   \end{enumerate}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Since the previous definition of the command uses `enumi`, the defined command `\setItemnumber` will only work for the first level for nested `enumerate`s. Using the `\@enumdepth` counter (controlling the nesting depth for enumerated lists), the command can be improved so as to be used for every level in nested enumerations:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \makeatletter
   \newcommand\setItemnumber[1]{\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \begin{enumerate}
     \setItemnumber{5}
     \item The fifth item
     \begin{enumerate}
       \setItemnumber{3}
       \item The third subitem
       \setItemnumber{9}
       \item The ninth subitem
     \end{enumerate}
     \setItemnumber{7}
     \item The seventh item
   \end{enumerate}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The result:

   [image]
2. Use the optional argument for `\item` (but you loose in this way the possibility to do cross-references to those items):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{enumerate}
     \item[5.] The fifth item
     \item[7.] The seventh item
   \end{enumerate}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: i know the version that adjusts the counter will work reliably with `\label` and `\ref`.  will the other work as well?  (i could try it, but having the answer here might help someone else too.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, it won't. I just added the remark.

Comment: Works, thx! :) `setcounter{enumi}{x}` would have done it, but your `newcommand` is a nice addition

Comment: @caligula You're welcome. Yes, the command is useful; using just `\setcounter{enumi}{x}` you would have to remember to use `n-1` to get `n`, the command does the calculation for you :)

Comment: Ok, I found a question: What is the `\relax` good for?

Comment: @caligula in this particular case, it instructs TeX to stop scanning for numbers.

Comment: @caligula You're welcome. I updated my answer with a more general version of the command which might be of interes for you.