# Long Enumerate in Long Table

Tags: longtable, enumerate

I would like to have a **LONG** enumerated list inside a (long)table and have the long list wrapped to the next page.  However, the longtable clips the enumerated list instead of wrapping it.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.8\linewidth}}
        Some text &
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A table cell cannot be split across pages. Do you really need a `longtable`?

Comment: I guess not, but I do need two "columns" that look like a table with horizontal and vertical rules to separate the rows and columns.  That is, I need it to resemble a table that wraps pages (even if I don't use a (long)table per se).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround with enumitem and its `resume*` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}%

    \begin{longtable}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.8\linewidth}}
        Some text & \begin{enumerate}[topsep= 0pt, partopsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, series=TE]
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
\end{enumerate} \\
    Some more text & \begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
                \item An enumerated item
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the nature of the lists (and possibly having to re-insert text above the table later), I'm looking for a solution that "automagically" breaks for me.  If this cannot be done with a table, I wonder if it can be with something that mimics the look of a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple tables, one per page, and change the number of the first item on each page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.8\linewidth}}
Some text &
\begin{enumerate}
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\end{enumerate}
\end{longtable}

\newcommand\setItemnumber[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.8\linewidth}}
Some text &
\begin{enumerate}
\setItemnumber{31}
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item
\item An enumerated item     
\end{enumerate}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Source: [How can I change the number of enumerate items?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255197/how-can-i-change-the-number-of-enumerate-items)

Comment: Having to figure out exactly where to break the page (especially since other text may need to be inserted later) can be challenging.