# Use of longtable and enumerate simultaneously

Tags: longtable, enumerate

I am preparing my CV. In order to add a section to list of my publications, I have tried the following, which is obtained from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491824/long-enumerate-in-long-table)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable, enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.7in, top=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent ~~ {\color{Blue}{Publications}}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.0in}p{6.1in}}
&
\begin{enumerate}[topsep= 0pt, partopsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, series=TE]
\item[{\bf \large $2022$}]
\end{enumerate}\\
&
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
\item First Author, Second Author, Third Author, {\it Third Paper Title,} {\bf Journal Name} Volume pp. 1--24 (2022).
\end{enumerate}\\
&
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
\item[{\bf \large $2021$}]
\end{enumerate}\\
&
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
\item First Author, Second Author, {\it Second Paper Title,} {\bf Journal Name,} Volume pp. 1--20 (2021).
\end{enumerate}\\
&
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
\item[{\bf \large $2020$}]
\end{enumerate}\\
&
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=TE]
\item First Author, Second Author, Third Author, Fourth Author {\it First Paper Title,} {\bf Journal Name} Volume pp. 1--15 (2020).
\end{enumerate}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The command `[resume*=TE]` is used to resume the enumitems in the next page.

The output is the following:

[image: output]

The year 2022 (on the extreme left) is in the right place, but 2021 and 2020 are not.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you like to have list in a long table? Far more simple is to have it without it ...

Comment: @Zarko I have no problem if it is simply done without longtable. But my list is long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of a long table for inserting list can make a lot of troubles at it breaking between pages, To my opinion is far more simple to use just `\enumerate` list:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{longtable, enumitem}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textcolor{Blue}{Publications}

\begin{enumerate}[align=right, leftmargin=3em]
\item[\large\textbf{2022}]
\item First Author, Second Author, Third Author, \textit{Third Paper Title}, \textbf{Journal Name} Volume pp. 1--24 (2022).
\item[\large\textbf{2021}]
\item First Author, Second Author, \textit{Second Paper Title}, \textbf{Journal Name}, Volume pp. 1--20 (2021).
\item[\large\textbf{2020}]
\item First Author, Second Author, Third Author, Fourth Author \textit{First Paper Title}, \textbf{Journal Name} Volume pp. 1--15 (2020).
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout).

**Note:**
The use of `it` and `\bf` is in LaTeX deprecate.. Instead of them, you should use `\itshape` or `\textit˙{...}` as in above MWE and `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}`.

Comment: thanks for this. But as I told my list is long and that continues to the next page. Thats why I use `[resume*=TE]`.

Comment: Apparently you not understood my answer.  It not use `longtable` , List `enumerate` can have as many items as you wish and can easily occupy many pages. For test, 
 copy last item in my answer 100 times and see result. In proposed solution a 7[resume*=,,,]` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this. Actually, I used longtable (two columns) in some previous sections. That's why I wanted enumerate and longtable simultaneously.